# split column into two with "/" separator in r

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have following type of data, although data.frame is very large.

```
A1 <- c("A/B", "A/A", "B/B", "A/A")
B1 <- c("B/B", "C/C", "C/B", "D/A")
C1 <- c("B/B", "C/C", "C/B", "D/A")
mydf <- data.frame (A1, B1, C1)
mymat <- as.matrix (mydf)
mymat
         A1    B1    C1   
[1,] "A/B" "B/B" "B/B"
[2,] "A/A" "C/C" "C/C"
[3,] "B/B" "C/B" "C/B"
[4,] "A/A" "D/A" "D/A"
```

I want split each columns into two "/" is sperator. Thus output would look like:

```
    A1a  A1b   B1a  B1b    C1a  C1b   
[1,] A   B      B    B     B     B 
[2,] A   A      C    C     C     C
[3,] B   B      C    B     C     B
[4,] A   A      D    A     D     A
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you should add the "apply" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution using reshape2's colsplit:

```
require(reshape2)
mymat <- as.data.frame(mymat)

LS <- lapply(seq_along(mymat), function(i){
    colsplit(mymat[, i], "/", paste0(colnames(mymat)[i], letters[1:2]))
    }
)

do.call('cbind', LS)
```

Which yields:

```
  A1a A1b B1a B1b C1a C1b
1   A   B   B   B   B   B
2   A   A   C   C   C   C
3   B   B   C   B   C   B
4   A   A   D   A   D   A
```

Comment: thanks, it is quite nice - little typo: "paste0" should be "paste"

Comment: @JohnCLK - R 2.15 added paste0 which is defined as `paste0(..., collapse) is equivalent to paste(..., sep = "", collapse), slightly more efficiently.`. From `?paste`: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html

Comment: thanks Chase, actually I need to update to 2.15...I am forgetting it

Answer (score 6):

Here's a mildly devious way. Add "/"'s between the characters and read in with that as separator:

```
splitdf <- read.table(text=capture.output(write.table(mydf, quote=FALSE, 
                                        sep="/",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)),
                       sep="/")
names(splitdf) <- paste( rep(names(mydf), each=2), c("a","b"), sep="")
 splitdf
#------------
  A1a A1b B1a B1b C1a C1b
1   A   B   B   B   B   B
2   A   A   C   C   C   C
3   B   B   C   B   C   B
4   A   A   D   A   D   A
```

Comment: that's genius.  I like this solution a lot. I'm betting this is the fastest easiest way yet.  Hope the poster looks back here at that solution.  +1

Comment: Any credit should probably devolve to @G-Grothendieck. The trick of converting to a text stream is one I learned from him.

Answer (score 4):

The following should do it in base R.

```
l <- apply(mymat, 2, function(m) data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(m, '/')), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)))
do.call(cbind, l)
```

Comment: I thought about this approach at first but `colsplit` is so nice I wne that route instead. +1  The flexibility of `colsplit`gives you exactly the column names the poster was asking for.

Comment: I like this function as this is much faster than reshape for my big data

Answer (score 0):

In shameless self-promotion of my "splitstackshape" package, here's another solution:

Your data (stopping at the `data.frame` stage and not converting it to a `matrix` as you did in your question):

```
A1 <- c("A/B", "A/A", "B/B", "A/A")
B1 <- c("B/B", "C/C", "C/B", "D/A")
C1 <- c("B/B", "C/C", "C/B", "D/A")
mydf <- data.frame (A1, B1, C1)
mydf
#    A1  B1  C1
# 1 A/B B/B B/B
# 2 A/A C/C C/C
# 3 B/B C/B C/B
# 4 A/A D/A D/A
```

Install and load the "splitstackshape" package, and use `concat.split.multiple" (which lets you split multiple columns at once) to get your desired output:

```
## install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(mydf, 1:3, "/")
#   A1_1 A1_2 B1_1 B1_2 C1_1 C1_2
# 1    A    B    B    B    B    B
# 2    A    A    C    C    C    C
# 3    B    B    C    B    C    B
# 4    A    A    D    A    D    A
```